# Derivation: Formula for projection of sun's motion onto parallel of declination

Tags: coordinate

Consider the projected angular velocity of the sun along a parallel of declination. I was told that it is $$\frac{\cos\varepsilon}{\cos\delta_{\odot}} \frac{d\ell_{\odot}}{dt} \tag{1}$$

where we let $\ell$ be the ecliptic longitude of the sun and $\varepsilon$ be the obliquity of the ecliptic.

The explanation given is to verify that when: $\delta_{\odot} = 0$ (Equinox), we have, $\cos\varepsilon \frac{d\ell_{\odot}}{dt}$; $\delta_{\odot} = \varepsilon$ (Solstice) gives $\frac{d\ell_{\odot}}{dt}$.

This seems more like a hint to me, that the function takes on a particular form and values at end points. ***Hence, how can we complete the derivation, using the hints given above?***

I am aware that the alternative derivation is to differentiate $\tan \alpha_{\odot} = \cos \varepsilon \tan{\ell_{\odot}}$ (After some substitutions, multiply by $\cos \delta_{\odot}$). ***However, I prefer a more intuitive, geometric argument.***

---

For more context:
Projecting onto the equator,
$$\frac{d \alpha_{\odot}}{dt} = \frac{\cos\varepsilon}{\cos^2 \delta_{\odot}} \frac{d\ell_{\odot}}{dt}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you're asking, you seem to have everything needed.

Comment: @Greg Miller I believe the derivation is far from complete... Maybe I'm too innocent to see it... Hence I was wondering whether anyone else knows how to complete it, using the hints given i.e. when: $\delta_{\odot} = 0$ (Equinox), we have, $\cos\varepsilon \frac{d\ell_{\odot}}{dt}$; $\delta_{\odot} = \varepsilon$ (Solstice) gives $\frac{d\ell_{\odot}}{dt}$.